# Code blocks with long lines don't wrap on iPad

Tags: support, code-block, ipad

Apple has decided not to allow DIVs to be scrolly.

This means I can't read code blocks with long lines on my iPad.

Comment: Not a correctly-worded question, but exactly the tip I was looking for; voting up. Can someone edit the q to make it fit the answer better?

Answer (score 6):

You can scroll the extra wide/long code divs using two fingers.

```
This is some reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaallllllllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyy wwwwiiiiiiiiiiidddde coooooooooode
This is some more reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaallllllllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyy wwwwiiiiiiiiiiidddde coooooooooode
```

Comment: Care to explain where you put them?

Comment: @Hans Scroll down to the code block div that doesn't wrap. Press the div with the tips of two fingers (I suggest the index and middle finger of your dominant hand) and drag left.  I'll add an example so you can try it here.

Comment: This is a good solution, but there are times when this is problematic for readability. what would be nice if there was a way to collapse the right column.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to add this functionality to any of your projects try this script - http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4